# How can I add a class to an input if the input is changed with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I coded the following in my form:

```
<td><input type="text" ng-model="row.title" /></td>
```

When I look at my DOM with Chrome developer tools I see the following:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="row.title" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
```

How can I make it so that when there is a change made to the input that the input has a class added to it?

Comment: Check for `ng-dirty` class that is automatically added to the input when it is changed. Then you can give to `ng-dirty` class your specific css properties

Answer (score 12):

There are two good ways to approach this problem:

**1. Use the built-in `ng-dirty` class that Angular puts on the element.**

When you change an input managed by Angular, it adds some CSS classes to the input for various states. These include:

- `ng-pristine` - the input has not been modified
- `ng-dirty` - the input has been modified

So, if you can modify your CSS to be based off the `.ng-dirty` class, you're good to go.

**2. Use a `form` directive with the `$dirty` flag.**

When you use a `form` element, Angular assigns a [`FormController` instance](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:form.FormController) on the scope with the same name as the `name` attribute on the form; each input inside the form gets attached to that FormController instance as a property, again with the same name as the `name` attribute on the input. For example,

```html
<form name="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="myInput">
</form>
```

gives you

```javascript
$scope.myForm.myInput
```

Each input property has some of its *own* properties on it, including `$pristine` and `$dirty`; these work just like the CSS classes listed above. Thus, you can check for the `$dirty` flag on the input and use `ng-class` to conditionally apply a class to the element. An example:

```html
<div ng-controller="MainController">
  <form name="myForm">
    <input name="myInput" ng-model="model" ng-maxlength="3"
      ng-class="{changed: myForm.myInput.$dirty}">
  </form>
</div>
```

You can find a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/BDB5b/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hNrEV/2/

The main idea is using `$scope.$watch` to watch for changes to the input box. I gave it an id of `rowTitle`, and used a directive called `watchRowTitle` that watches for changes to `$scope.row.title`, and adds a class 'red' that colors the text red whenever the text in the input box is equal to 'wrong title'.

It is probably good practice to do DOM manipulation in directives. Here, the `watchRowTitle` directive returns an object with 4 keys:

- **template** - the html that replaces the `watch-row-title` tag. we dont need this here
- **scope** - Here we make use of an isolated scope. Basically, the '=' establishes a 2-way data binding between between `scope.title` inside the `watch-row-title` directive and the `$scope.row.title` value inside the `MyCtrl` controller.
- **restrict** - We give it a value of `E`, which stands for element. So this restricts the use of the `watch-row-title` directive within html tags, in other words: `<watch-row-title></watch-row-title>`
- **link** - this is the link function, where the interesting stuff happens. In here, we use `scope.$watch` on `title`. We have to supply a function with 2 parameters `newValue` and `oldValue` (you can name them to something else, but naming them this way is more meaningful), that holds the new and old values of the variable being watched. Whenever the `scope.title` variable becomes the string 'wrong title', it adds the CSS class 'red' to the input box with id `rowTitle` (notice how the text in the input box turns red). Otherwise, it removes that CSS class. This portion is done using JQuery.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input id="rowTitle" type="text" ng-model="row.title" class="ng-pristine ng-valid" />
    <watch-row-title title="row.title"></watch-row-title>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.red {
    color: red;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('MyCtrl', [
        '$scope',
        function ($scope) {
            $scope.row = {};
        }
    ])
    .directive('watchRowTitle', [
        function () {
            return {
                template: '',
                scope: {
                    title: '='
                },
                restrict: 'E',
                link: function(scope, element, attr) {
                    scope.$watch('title', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                        if (newValue === 'wrong title') {
                            $('#rowTitle').addClass('red');
                        } else {
                            $('#rowTitle').removeClass('red');
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="inputTitle" ng-model="row.title" />
```

**JS**

```
$scope.$watch('row.title', function(newValue) {
   // Add CSS class on input
   $('#inputTitle').addClass('YourCSSClass');
}, true);
```

Comment: and what if you haven't jQuery?

Comment: You must have lite jQuery or Zepto with AngularJS ;)

Comment: absolutely no , but what you have is jqLite. so the question actually is how to do what you did with jqLite ?

Comment: "Does Angular use the jQuery library?
Yes, Angular can use jQuery if it's present in your app when the application is being bootstrapped. If jQuery is not present in your script path, Angular falls back to its own implementation of the subset of jQuery that we call jQLite."

Comment: exactly. so i'm asking how can you do it with jqLite ?

Comment: From the [AngularJS FAQ](http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq) "Common Pitfalls": "Stop trying to use jQuery to modify the DOM in controllers. Really. That includes adding elements, removing elements, retrieving their contents, showing and hiding them. Use built-in directives, or write your own where necessary, to do your DOM manipulation."

Comment: It's an anti-pattern to manipulate dom inside the controller.