# angular change class on $dirty

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular js and am trying to add some animations in my login page.

I have written a controller which would change class of the input field on click and on blur.

```
app.controller("con", function($scope,$rootScope,$http,$location){
  $scope.OnClick = function(event){
      $scope.username1 = "active";
      $scope.password1 = "active";
      };

  $scope.OnBlurUserName = function(event){
      if(this.username)
          $scope.username1 = "active";
      else{
          $scope.username1 = "input"; 
      }
      };
      $scope.OnBlurPassword = function(event){
          if(this.password)
              $scope.password1 = "active";
          else{
              $scope.password1 = "input"; 
          }
          };
});


        <div class = "input" ng-class="username1" ng-controller="con">
        <label class="label">Username</label>
        <input class="field" name="username" type="text" ng-model="username" 
        ng-click="OnClick()" ng-blur="OnBlurUserName(username)" required>

        <div class="input" ng-class="password1" ng-controller="con"> 
        <label class="label">Password</label>
        <input name="password" class="field" type="password" ng-    model="password"
        ng-click="OnClick()" ng-touched="OnClick()" ng-blur="OnBlurPassword(password)" required>
```

What is happening is click on username and password the class are being changed. But if i enter something in username and press a tab button and enter something in password the class is not being changed.

How do i check is the user has started entering the input and apply the same class that i am applying on click?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed it by adding ng-focus also along with ng-click.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the *ng-class* directive in your input and adapt it to your needs:

```
ng-class="{'your-class': yourForm.yourInputsName.$dirty}"
```

Here's a great answer [How can I add a class to an input if the input is changed with AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648114/how-can-i-add-a-class-to-an-input-if-the-input-is-changed-with-angularjs#answer-17648994)

Also here is a great article on forms validation and manipulation with AngularJS https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation